# warnings about case_sensitive can't be erased

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When I test with rspec, below WARNING is displayed everytime.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Uniqueness validator will no longer enforce case sensitive comparison in Rails 6.1. To continue case sensitive comparison on the :email attribute in User model, pass `case_sensitive: true` option explicitly to the uniqueness validator. (called from block (2 levels) in <main> at /usr/src/app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:6)
```

So I tried to write this to User.rb(I expect case insensitive).

> validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

But, the WARNING can't be erased.

Next, I checked devise.rb(because I used devise and devise_token_auth). In devise.rb, it was written about case_insensitive.

> config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

For your reference...

User.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  has_many :schedules

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10 }
  validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11

  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 6..128

  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete

end
```

Why rails don't stop WARNING?

thanks for your help.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion among the developers about where this message is coming from, see https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/1345

Answer (score 4):

You shuld be able to change in your User.rb

```
#User.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  # From  
  validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  # To
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, case_sensitive: true
end
```

Comment: sorry for my late reply.
i tried it with case_sensitive: false. But warning didn't be erased.
thank you for answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found this warning is caused by devise_token_auth gem.

So I changed setting in config/initializers/devise_token_auth.rb

```
config.default_callbacks = false
```

But after this change, all email validation by devise is disabled.
So I decided to hide WARNING with below in config/application.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true if Rails.version == '6.0.2.2'
```